# How to build app to fit all screen size in android xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, screen-size

I'm creating my first app and it's very simple, and while creating it i tested the app on my phone (gs3  4.8 inches). However, when i tested it with different phones the whole thing was distorted. I was wondering how i could fix it or if I built the whole thing wrong. I don't have enough reputation points to post an image but I'll describe what happens. I have a background image with buttons on top of it and the buttons have to be in a very specific spot and if the arn't the whole thing look s messed up. My code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivReturnedPic"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/newbeach3" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"

android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginRight="300dp"
android:layout_marginTop="570dp"
android:text="Intensity:" />

 SeekBar
android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
android:layout_width="355dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="590dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="top" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bvibrate2"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
    android:background="@drawable/piece2"
    android:text="Pattern 2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bvibrate1"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="187dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
    android:background="@drawable/piece1"
    android:text="Pattern 1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bvibrate3"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="187dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="291dp"
    android:background="@drawable/piece3"
    android:text="Pattern 3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bvibrate4"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="291dp"
    android:background="@drawable/piece4"
    android:text="Pattern 4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bvibrate6"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="407dp"
    android:background="@drawable/piece6"
    android:text="Pattern 6" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bvibrate5"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="187dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="407dp"
    android:background="@drawable/piece5"
    android:text="Pattern 5" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bvibrate7"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="187dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="523dp"
    android:background="@drawable/piece7"
    android:text="Pattern 7" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bvibrate8"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="523dp"
    android:background="@drawable/piece8"
    android:text="Pattern 8" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bstop"
    android:layout_width="87dp"
    android:layout_height="87dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/bvibrate1"
    android:layout_marginRight="29dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:background="@drawable/square"
    android:text="Stop" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Perhaps you can programmatically set the width/height of the buttons instead of setting the values in XML.

Comment: this my help you http://petrnohejl.github.io/Android-Cheatsheet-For-Graphic-Designers/

Answer (score 0):

to handle this changes you'll have to create layout-large and layout-xlarge in your res folder. and then copy your layout.xml from layout folder and paste inside of the two new folders you created. and then from `eclipse` `Graphical Layout` you'll see how your layout will look like in different devices and from there you'll have to edit the layouts to fit into other screen sizes. this is the easiest way to handle different screens in android. hope that helped you.